# Jenkins Git-Push with master branch only

Tags: jenkins, github

This might be a very basic question in terms of jenkins and github integration. However, I am thinking good to ask.

What I am basically looking to do is if anything pushed to master branch of git only then my jenkins job must get triggered. Considering there are multiple feature branches and multiple commits happening on different branches but I am interested only in master branch push.

I did not find good documentation over, could anybody give me any pointer on this.

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you using a Jenkinsfile or the Web-UI?

Comment: @Michael, Does it behave differently for jenkinsfile and web-ui. I am using Jenkinsfile.

Comment: probably not, but in case of a Jenkinsfile I can answer in code and not screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you got two options:

### Create a single branch pipeline

Just click on create new item, select pipeline and under "Pipeline" configure as "Pipeline script from SCM" and put your GitHub and in "branches to build" put "*/master".

### Add brach conditions

Alternatively you could add [`when` conditions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) to your stages if you use declarative syntax:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {

        stage("Build") {
            when { branch 'master' }
            steps {
                // do your build
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you're using scripted:

```
node {
    stage('Build') {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            // do your build
        }
    }
}
```

See ["flow control"](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control).

Comment: How will this job gets triggered when something pushed to master ? don't we need to configure github to push to jenkins ?

Comment: I have not much experience regarding GitHub and Jenkins, but with Bitbucket, you just set the push trigger and due to the "branches to build" setting Jenkins is only triggered for that branch.